# TranslateZ and Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have a div that I'm animating and I'm using the good old translateZ hack to force hardware acceleration:

```
#random{
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
       -o-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Everything works fine in all browsers, except in safari 5.1. In safari the whole div just does not render, you can mark the text etc, but it's transparent.

Removing the transform solves the problem but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It should work :
http://caniuse.com/transforms3d

If not maybe try sandpaper plugin:

**SANDPAPER** 
https://github.com/pbakaus/transformie

Comment: just tried transform3d but it didn't work, I was able however to enable hardware acceleration with backface-visibility:hidden; and it rendering everything as it should